# Remove files with 0 length inside bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create a bash script inside Linux terminal to go into a file and then delete it if it's empty:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo " Enter name of a directory"
read Dir
for Directory in $( ls $HOME )
do 
  test -d $HOME/$dir
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then 
    for filename in $( ls $HOME/$Dir )
    do 
      test -d $HOME/$dir/$filename
      if [ ! -s "$filename"  ]
      then
        rm $HOME/$dir/$filename
      else 
        echo " not empty"
      fi 
    done 
  else 
    echo " $Dir is not a directory" 
  fi 
done
```

This is the code I am using but it does not work. It recognizes the file created but doesn't delete it even when empty. It Salah displays there is no such file or directory

Comment: `$Dir` is NOT equal to `$dir` FYI...Shell variables are case sensitive. UNIX is not like windows or IBM mainframes

Comment: given a directory name, you would like to remove all files with zero size in this directory, right?

Comment: @MelBurslan That was a manual error while writing the script here
I am using the same variables but still not working

Comment: @Jay Yes exactly
taking the directory as a command line argument and then checking if its empty 
if yes then deleting the files

Comment: @Jay for the code you gave it says you have specified maxdepth option after a non option argument but options are not positional

Comment: Please only paste the exact code that you have tested. Having us look at the wrong code wastes our time.

Answer (score 5):

**Edited 1 (Erik Renouf) to stick to [find as specified at The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html)**

**Edited 2 (WildCard) + sign and raw {}**

Give this a try, replace **mydir** in the command-line below with a directory name that needs to be worked out:

```
find "${HOME}"/mydir -size 0 -type f -exec rm {} +
```

It is removing all empty files located in the "${HOME}"/mydir directory and its subdirectories (if any).

There is a script version below:

```
#!/bin/bash --
find "${HOME}"/"${1}" -size 0 -type f -exec rm {} +
```

---

**T E S T**

List all empty files under **testd**:

```
$ find "${HOME}"/testd -size 0 -type f
/home/jay/testd/empty_file.txt
```

Use the script to remove empty files:

```
$ chmod +x clearner.sh
$ ./clearner.sh testd
```

Check for empty files:

```
$ find "${HOME}"/testd -size 0 -type f
$
```

Comment: Since `-empty` is a GNU specific flag, why not just use `-delete` instead of `-exec rm`?

Comment: thx I am not at my computer so I checked on the net one online **man** before answering. I missed this gnu thing and the delete. I will edit the answer.

Comment: thx @EricRenouf the answer had been edited and tested.

Comment: You don't need to escape the braces.  They have no special meaning to the shell when adjacent (i.e. empty).  Also, +1 for sticking to POSIX.  Have you considered using `+` instead of `\;`?

Comment: thx @Wildcard I had never noticed the + sign neither the possibility to use raw {}. I used to practice on Solaris 6 - 7 - 8, maybe that is why ?

Comment: Thx to both: I have learnt something today :)

Answer (score 3):

I do like using `find` for this since it will handle filenames with special characters well.  You could do it with GNU `find` similar to how @Jay suggested or more portably like

```
find "$HOME/$dir" -type f -size 0c -exec rm {} +
```

which will look in `$HOME/mydir` and all subdirectories.  Everything that is a file (`-type f`) and has a size of 0 bytes (-size 0c) will then have its name applied as an argument to `rm`, and we'll let the command line have many arguments instead of invoking `rm` for each file (the `+` instead of a `\;` to `-exec`)

If you do not want to descend into subdirectories and want it to be portable you could do the following, which I'm going to put into a subshell so as not to change from the current directory in the current shell:

```
( cd "$HOME/$dir"; find . ! -name . -prune -type f -size 0c -exec rm {} + )
```

This will use `-prune` to prevent `find` from going into further directories, and will throw away the `.` directory which will prevent it from being part of the directory list that gets descended.  Those two result in `find` only reporting results from the current directory.

Now that we're in the current directory we can revisit the script you were writing though since we're much closer to that approach again.

You should be careful with the approach you were trying in your script.  Any file with a character in `IFS` (like a space or tab) would cause your for loop to be looking at partial filenames (e.g., if a file is called `with space` you would get `with` and `space` in different iterations).  If you're going to loop over files in a directory it is better to use globs like

```
for f in $HOME/$dir/*; do
    if [ -f "$f" ] && [ ! -s "$f" ]; then
       printf "It's an empty file: %s" "$f"
    fi
done
```

This glob solution will not pick up any files that start with a `.` though unless you enable dotglob.